# .NET Core: Swagger 3 / Swashbuckle - Auto-Expand Array of Possible Enum Values in UI

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm trying to get the following arrays of possible enum values in model/schema property on an endpoint to auto-expand so the user doesn't have to manually click the dropdown on each one.
[Model property view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcS0V.png)

I see from the below GitHub issue it may not have been implemented properly in Swagger UI yet, but I was thinking that surely Swashbuckle would have a way of implementing this by now:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4313

I've tried searching a number of different avenues in the `SwaggerGenOptions`, `OpenApiInfo`, `SwaggerOptions`, and `SwaggerUiOptions` objects but can't find anything that fits.

Comment: There seems to be no similar configuration in [swagger-ui Parameters](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#apply-swagger-ui-parameters). Perhaps you can [customize the Swagger Index Page](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#customize-indexhtml) and then do something like this: [Expand all Models at once](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6494).